# udf with scipy on amazon emr jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, scipy, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I have troubles running scipy functions as a udf in pyspark.

I am running a jupyter notebook on an EMR instance. Necessary python packages were installed by ssh-ing onto the master node and using, e.g.

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

From what I have understood this should install the package on all nodes. I am now trying to run the anova-function scipy.stats.f_oneway, which works fine in the non-distributed mode:

```py
# testing the function locally
scipy.stats.f_oneway([32,4,4], [321,43,4]).pvalue


0.3366941400375204
```

However, when I try to create a udf function to run it with pyspark:

```py
# calculate anova p-value
def anova_pvalue(normal_cols, tumor_cols):
    s = scipy.stats.f_oneway(normal_cols, tumor_cols).pvalue
    return(s.item())
# register as udf
udf_anova_pvalue = f.udf(anova_pvalue, DoubleType())

# apply anova udf 
df_result = df_result.withColumn('anova',udf_anova_pvalue(f.array(normal_cols), f.array(tumor_cols))).select('Protein_gene', 'log2FC', 'anova').toPandas()
```

I get the error message 'ImportError: No module named scipy.stats' (full message below). It somehow seems the scipy isn't properly installed on the worker-nodes?

Thanks for your help!

```
An error occurred while calling o11539.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 59, ip-172-31-45-16.eu-central-1.compute.internal, executor 4): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 583, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2041)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2262)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2211)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2200)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 583, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2142, in toPandas
    pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 533, in collect
    sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o11539.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 59, ip-172-31-45-16.eu-central-1.compute.internal, executor 4): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 583, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2041)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2262)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2211)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2200)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 583, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1564560726600_0001/container_1564560726600_0001_01_000008/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install `scipy` on all nodes you need to use [bootstrap actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html).
Your script should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo easy_install-3.6 pip
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install scipy 
exit 0
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, but shouldn't ```sudo pip install scipy``` on the worker node do exactly the same thing? (I'm using python 2.7 by the way)

Comment: No,it will only install it on master.